# Is there a way to search all fields with redis-om-spring using the EntityStream API?

Tags: redis, redisearch, redis-om-spring

In [redis-om-spring](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring) I can search all fields by simply adding a search method to the repository.

```
public interface ProductRepository extends RedisDocumentRepository<Product, String> {
    Page<Product> search(String text, Pageable pageable);
}
```

When using the EntityStream, I can search on specific fields, but not across all fields.

```
var result = entityStream.of(Product.class)
   .anyMatch(new StartsWithPredicate<>(Product$.UNIQUE_ID.getField(),"100790"))

@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product{
   @Id
   String uniqueId;
   @Searchable
   String field1;
   @Searchable   
   String field2;
   @Searchable
   String fieldN;
}

repo.save(new Product("UA","searchForA1","searchForA2","searchForAN");
repo.save(new Product("UB","searchForB1","searchForB2","searchForBN");
repo.save(new Product("UC","searchForC1","searchForC2","searchForCN");
```

I need to search across all fields. Am I missing something in the EntityStream API or is this not possible?

Something that generates:

```
FT.SEARCH my-idx "thesearchTerm"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a `filter` method in the `SearchStream` interface that takes a free-form text String:

```java
SearchStream<E> filter(String freeText);
```

See https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/main/redis-om-spring/src/main/java/com/redis/om/spring/search/stream/SearchStream.java#L20

Comment: We're having some issues with MavenCentral but should be resolved by the end of the week (01/27)

Comment: Thanks, I see it's released 